# Setting up different show times for my Shield UI JavaScript chart datapoints

Tags: javascript, charts, shieldui

I have some special need regarding the introductory animation of my Shield UI JavaScript chart. Using the property

```
 applyAnimation: {
     duration: 1000
 },
```

I need to be able to set different delay times for all of the bars in my chart. For instance the first bar to show in for 1000 milliseconds, the second one faster and so on. I looked in the documentation and couldn’t find anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applyAnimation property can be used in two ways- applied to the whole chart and all it’s series, or per data series. In this respect you may achieve a similar to the desired behavior by specifying a different show delay time (shall there be more than one data series, of course). To do so you may use code like this one:

```
    dataSeries: [
        {
            seriesType: 'bar',
            applyAnimation: {
                duration: 1000
            },
            data: [
                1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5

            ]
        },
        {
            seriesType: 'bar',
            applyAnimation: {
                duration: 2000
            },
            data: [
                5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4, 5, 1, 3, 4
            ]
        }
    ]
```

The data series is he smallest scope of the property’s application. In other words it can’t be applied for a single bar for instance.